# How to delegate defects to developers by tester in ALM tool?

Tags: quality-center, development-process, techniques

How to delegate defects to developers by tester in ALM tool?

Comment: Maybe you can give a bit more context and explain how you are working now and why this leads to this question. What have you tried?

Comment: Agree @NielsvanReijmersdal. Kaushik - Pls add details so you will get max strong solution.

Answer (score 2):

Testers should never delegate or assign defects to developers. The tester have a signaling function, you signal that something is out of order. Now someone else should decide what to-do with this signal, for example the owner of the product could prioritize based on risks and feature importance.

**Testers in a dev-team**:
When testers are working in a team then I would expect the tester to just communicate that he/she found defects. Only place them in a ALM tool if you are going to postpone the defect fixing. I suggest a [zero defect policy](https://medium.com/quality-functions/the-zero-bug-policy-b0bd987be684#.q3jma7gu4) for teams and pick up found issues as soon as possible.

**Testers outside a dev-team**:
Testers record defects in a ALM tool, with step-by-step reproduction path. Then project owners/managers should monitor incoming defects and prioritize them accordingly. Then assign them to a team (or to a individual developer, but developers should always work in teams if you ask me). The team should schedule fixing the defect depending on the priority. Again I suggest to use a [zero defect policy](https://medium.com/quality-functions/the-zero-bug-policy-b0bd987be684#.q3jma7gu4).